# How can one parse whole XML documents using the LXML Sax module?

Tags: python, lxml, sax, saxparser

I have a script that goes through a directory with many XML files and extracts or adds information to these files. I use XPath to identify the elements of interest.

The relevant piece of code is this:

```
import lxml.etree as et
import lxml.sax

 
# deleted non relevant code

 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):   

        # iterate all files
        for file in files:
            
            if file.endswith('.xml'):

                # join root dir and file name
                file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, file)

                # load root element from file
                file_root = et.parse(file_path).getroot()
        
                # This is a function that I define elsewhere in which I use XPath to identify relevant 
                # elements and extract, change or add some information
                xml_dosomething(file_root)
                
                # init tree object from file_root
                tree = et.ElementTree(file_root)

                # save modified xml tree object to file with an added text so that I can keep a copy of original. 
                
                tree.write(file_path.replace('.xml', '-clean.xml'), encoding='utf-8', doctype='<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "estcorpus.dtd">', xml_declaration=True)
```

I have seen in various places that people recommend using Sax(on) to speed up the processing of large files. After checking the documentation of the LXML Sax module in (https://lxml.de/sax.html) I'm at a loss as to how to modify my code so that I can leverage the Sax module. I can see the following in the documentation:

```
handler = lxml.sax.ElementTreeContentHandler()
```

then there is a list of statements like (handler.startElementNS((None, 'a'), 'a', {})) that would populate the 'handler' "document" (?) with what would be the elements of a the XML document. After that I see:

```
tree = handler.etree
lxml.etree.tostring(tree.getroot())
```

I think I understand what handler.etree does but my problem is that I want 'handler' to be the files in the directory that I'm working with rather than a string that I create by using 'handler.startElementNS' and the like. What do I need to change in my code to get the Sax module to do the work that needs to be done with the files as input?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you have a subtle bug in the path handling - while you have `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOT):`, you use `file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, file)`, which should probably be `file_path = os.path.join(root, file)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @dskrypa. It is not a bug. It is intended. ROOT is a variable defined at the beginning with the string corresponding to the path to the folder with the XML files. Capitals are to prevent confusion with other possible uses of 'root' within the code.

Comment: If you ever have a sub-directory that contains XML files, the current code will not work as intended.  If you don't need to use `os.walk`, then it may be better to use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [Path.iterdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) instead.

Comment: That's important to know. Thanks for the tip, @dskrypa!

Comment: "What do I need to change in my code...?" - Basically you need to rewrite it from scratch. SAX is event-based and very different from the way you work when the entire XML document is loaded into memory. A SAX parser reads XML and fires events. You need to implement callback methods in response to these events.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn. That complicates things too much.